# Add same value to multiple sets of rows. The value changes based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is dynamically created.
I create my first set of rows as:

```
df['tourist_spots'] = pd.Series(<A list of tourist spots in a city>)
```

To this df I add:

```
df['city'] = <City Name>
```

So far so good. A bunch of rows are created with the same city name for multiple tourist spots.

I want to add a new city. So I do:

```
df['tourist_spots'].append(pd.Series(<new data>))
```

Now, when I append a new city with:

```
df['city'].append('new city')
```

the previously updated city data is gone. It is as if every time the rows are replaced and not appended.

Here's an example of what I want:

Step 1:

```
df['tourist_spot'] = pd.Series('Golden State Bridge' + a bunch of other spots)
```

For all the rows created by the above data I want:

```
df['city'] = 'San Francisco'
```

Step 2:

```
df['tourist_spot'].append(pd.Series('Times Square' + a bunch of other spots)
```

For all the rows created by the above data, I want:

```
df['city'] = 'New York'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you specify your existing df and your final output as text, please?

Comment: Create different, separate data frames, and then `pd.concat` them all

Comment: Thanks, rafaelc.

Comment: @cs95, There is no existing dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use dictionary to add rows to your data frame**, it is faster method.
Here is an e.g.

**STEP 1** 
Create dictionary:

```
dict_df = [{'tourist_spots': 'Jones LLC', 'City': 'Boston'},
     {'tourist_spots': 'Alpha Co',  'City': 'Boston'},
     {'tourist_spots': 'Blue Inc',  'City': 'Singapore' }]
```

**STEP2**
Convert dictionary to dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
```

**STEP3**
Add new entries to dataframe in dictionary format:

```
df = df.append({'tourist_spots': 'New_Blue',  'City': 'Singapore'}, ignore_index=True)
```

**References:**

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html